# Como alterar este objeto JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, datagrid

Estou há alguns dias com o seguinte problema: Estou usando CakePHP e enviando JSON para um *datagrid* do EasyUI da seguinte forma:

```php
$rows = $this->Produto->find('all', array('fields' => array(
   'id', 'codigo_produto', 'codigo_pedido'
)));
$total = $this->Produto->find('count');
return new CakeResponse(
    array('type' => 200,
          'body' =>  json_encode(array('rows' => $rows,
                                       'total' => $total)
                                 )
    )
);
```

Porém meu maior problema é que ele está sendo enviado desta forma:

```json
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "Produto": {
                "id": "28",
                "codigo_produto": "01.02.00.0001",
                "codigo_pedido": "123521"
            }
        },
        {
            "Produto": {
                "id": "29",
                "codigo_produto": "",
                "codigo_pedido": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "Produto": {
                "id": "30",
                "codigo_produto": "03.02.01.0000",
                "codigo_pedido": "12351"
            }
        },
        {
            "Produto": {
                "id": "31",
                "codigo_produto": "02.01.00.2541",
                "codigo_pedido": "12351"
            }
        }
    ],
    "total": 4
}
```

Porém o *datagrid* o EasyUI só consegue carregar se o `data` estive assim:

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "28",
            "codigo_produto": "01.02.00.0001",
            "codigo_pedido": "123521"
        },
        {
            "id": "29",
            "codigo_produto": "",
            "codigo_pedido": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "30",
            "codigo_produto": "03.02.01.0000",
            "codigo_pedido": "12351"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "codigo_produto": "02.01.00.2541",
            "codigo_pedido": "12351"
        }
    ],
    "total": 4
}
```

O Cake envia como objeto mas não estou conseguindo tratar no Javascript pra ele alterar depois de receber nem no php do cake antes de enviar. Alguém tem algum conselho ai?

O *datagrid* não tem segredo:

```js
 $(function () {
    $('#dg').datagrid({
        url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'get_data')); ?>',
        pagination: true,
        columns: [[
            {field: 'id', title: 'id', width: 100},
            {field: 'codigo_produto', title: 'codigo produto', width: 100},
            {field: 'codigo_pedido', title: 'codigo pedido', width: 100, align: 'center'}
        ]]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhando para a documentação do [`.map()`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::map) parece-me que podes fazer assim no CakePHP:

```
$collection = new Collection($rows);
$new = $collection->map(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value["Produto"];
});
$result = $new->toArray();
```

Infelismente nõ tenho onde testar, mas o que precisas é iterar essa array e em cada elemento da array substituir `["Produto":{}}` pelo objeto interior com a chave `"Produto"`.